# How to simplify 2 modular operators?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

Is it possible to simplify the following expression? I feel like this can be simplified.

$$N = (7 - ((3X - C)\mod 7))\mod 7$$

$$A = \left\lfloor\frac{X + O}{7}\right\rfloor$$

I'll explain a bit for sake of completeness:

The formula is used to get [key signature value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signature#Major_scale_structure), where:

- $0\leq N \lt7$ starting from note C to B
- $-7\leq X\leq 7$ number of sharps or flats. Negative value means flats and positive means sharps.
- $C = 0$ for major scales, $C = 5$ for minor scales.
- $-1\leq A\leq 1$ negative value indicates flat key, positive indicates sharp key.
- $O = 1$ for major scales, $O = 4$ for minor scales.

I think It is possible to somehow simplify $\mod7 \mod7$ part. the formula I wrote is experimental but it works fine for defined ranges that I tested.

*Example:*

```
X = 4; // 4 sharps
C = 5; // minor scale
O = 4; // minor scale
```

$N = (7 - ((3\times 4 - 5)\mod 7))\mod 7\implies N = 0$ , therefore Note C

$A = \left\lfloor\frac{4+4}{7}\right\rfloor\implies A = 1 , A > 0$, therefore is sharp.

So key signature is C# minor

Comment: your example is wrong, you have X=4

Comment: thanks for correction. yes c# minor has 4 sharps. 3 was typo @JonMarkPerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first $7$ is redundant, you can use:

$$C-3X \pmod 7$$

instead.

Comment: this doesn't work for all cases. for example when X = 1 and C = 0 (G major) instead of giving N = 4 it gives N = -3. I'm not sure if I'm mistaken something?

Comment: oh I see. the language I use is C# and the modulus operator in C# is not giving expected mathematic result for negative numbers. the function you give is correct by the way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by just adding 21 units to constants. C = 21 for major and C = 26 for minor scales. this will cause the result to be always positive. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16023027/4767498

Comment: some mod implementations do this automatically; in maths we write: $$-3\equiv 4 \pmod 7$$, you can also use, if (retValue<0) retvalue+=7; but I'm glad you've worked it out.